# UTF-8 decoding help needed

Tags: javascript, xml, utf-8

I would like the change the layout of a web application but it is UTF-8 encoded. I have managed to use some online decoders and I know which part to modify but the decoding doesn't seem fully complete to work.

I want to move the div tag marked with * inside the previous one so instead of two lines I can have the data on one line which gives more on screen space.

```
<li class='ipsDataItem chat_row {{#callme}}ipsDataItem_new{{/callme}}' id='{{id}}'>
<div class='ipsPad_half {{#memberPhoto}}ipsPhotoPanel ipsPhotoPanel_tiny{{/memberPhoto}} ipsClearfix'>
    {{#memberPhoto}}
        <a href='{{memberUrl}}' class='ipsUserPhoto ipsUserPhoto_tiny' id='ips_uid_{{memberID}}'>
            <img src='{{memberPhoto}}' alt=''>
        </a>
    {{/memberPhoto}}
    <div>
        <a href='#' data-action='mention' data-member='{{memberName}}'>{{{memberNameFormat}}}</a>
        <span class='ipsPos_right'>
            <span class='ipsType_small ipsType_light'>{{time}}</span>
            {{#canEdit}}<a href='#' data-action='editMSGButton' data-id='{{id}}'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square'></i></a>{{/canEdit}}
            {{#canDelete}}<a href='#' data-action='remove' data-id='{{id}}'><i class='fa fa-minus-square'></i></a>{{/canDelete}}
        </span>
        * <div class='ipsList_inline' id='chatraw_{{id}}' data-id='{{id}}' {{#canEdit}}data-action='editMSG'{{/canEdit}}>{{{message}}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

This is the original encoded xml: https://pastebin.com/papiW75B
and this is what I managed to decode: https://pastebin.com/q24UfAEn. As you can see, the beginning part (line 1) is still a total mess but from line 2 forward it's all good.

What am I missing here? Should I do the decoding in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't describe that as being "UTF-8 encoded". It looks to me like obfuscated Javascript. It looks to me as if it's been deliberately obfuscated in order to prevent you doing what you are trying to do -- which I would describe more as reverse engineering rather than decoding. (Indeed, what you are trying to do might well be technically illegal unless you have permission from the copyright owner).

You've already done quite a good job at defeating the intentions of the people who created this application, and I don't think I can help you do any better.